# How to create an array from content parts

Tags: php

I want to read a file into an array and use some of the content from the file as array keys.

Example

myfile.txt

```
 [SPLIT]
 #START:KEY1
 this is the content 
 #END:KEY1
 [SPLIT]
 #START:KEY2
 this is the next content 
 #END:KEY2
 ...
```

I load the content from the file

```
$File = file_get_contents(myfile.txt);
```

I split the content at the maker [SPLIT] and create a array

```
    $file_array = explode('[SPLIT]',$File);
    
    foreach($file_array as $element)
    {
      //search for '#START:' get the part after that till lineend, use this as ($key) a key for a new array
....
      $new[$key]=$element;
    }
```

**So, my question is, is there a easier or faster way, to create a array from the filecontent which looks like?**

```
$myarray[KEY1]=this is the content
$myarray[KEY2]=this is the next content
```

Comment: What's your reason for using your own format instead of something simple like JSON? What's your reason for having starts, ends _and_ splits, when you could simply use `GROUP:KEY1`, since your keys can't be inside of eachother anyway (at least I guess they can't)?

Comment: youre right, end end-marker has no function. Could you give me a example about GROUP:KEY1!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried to use regular expresions?

```
$content = file_get_contents('file_name.txt');
preg_match_all('/\[SPLIT\]\n#START:(.*?)\n(.*?)#END/s', $content, $rows);

$data = [];
foreach ($rows[1] as $i => $key) {
    $data[$key] = trim($rows[2][$i]);
}
```

Comment: that looks like what i was looking for, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Greg you can also try to simplify the foreach loop manipulating the preg_match_all $flag parameter -> http://php.net/preg_match_all

Answer (score 0):

This will split based on new line :

```
$File = file('tmp/myfile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```